# Firebase realtime database and RecyclerView - How to prevent items blinking

Tags: android, firebase

I fetch data that is constantly changing from Firebase realtime database. 
Then I check if an item exists in an ArrayList, I don't add it, but if it does, I add and notify that the item was inserted. But, since the database is constantly changing, the entire list is "blinking". How can I add remove items inside the database listener, without making it blink? i.e only add/remove the specific item that is changing. This is the code now:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           if (x<token){
               if (!myDataset.contains(datas.getKey().toString())){
               int position = myDataset.indexOf(datas.getKey().toString());
               myDataset.add(datas.getKey().toString());
               mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myDataset.size() - 1);                
           }

      } else {       
         myDataset.remove(datas.getKey().toString());
         int position = myDataset.indexOf(datas.getKey().toString());
         mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code notifies the adapter of each individual item in the list, whenever there are any changes. The smallest possible change that will reduce the blinking is to move the notifying of the adapter outside of your loop:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    bool isChanged = false;
    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      if (x<token){
        if (!myDataset.contains(datas.getKey().toString())){
          int position = myDataset.indexOf(datas.getKey().toString());
          myDataset.add(datas.getKey().toString());
          isChanged = true;
        }
      } else {       
        myDataset.remove(datas.getKey().toString());
        int position = myDataset.indexOf(datas.getKey().toString());
        isChanged = true;
      }
      if (isChanged) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
      }
    }
}
```

Now for any update to the values, you will only notify the adapter (and hence force it to repaint) only once.

I'd recommend a different approach though. Since you are interested in additions and removal of child nodes, it is likely more efficient to use a `ChildEventListener`. This listener has callback methods for specific changes, such as `onChildAdded`, and `onChildRemoved`, that get called when a child is added or removed respectively. These callbacks get the precise information you need t update your `myDataset`.

You should still also use a `ValueEventListener` to detect when all changes have been received, and user that to notify the adapter of the changes, so that it rerenders the view. Since `ValueEventListener` is guaranteed to fire after the corresponding `ChildEventListener` callbacks, this sequence will work.

So:

- Use a `ChildEventListener` to listen to more granular changes, to allow direct updates of the `myDataset` without having to loop and detect it yourself.
- Use a `ValueEventListener` to detect when the child-level changes are done, and notify the adapter that it needs to repaint the view.

For a small example of this approach in production code, see [the `FirebaseArray` class in the FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java).